# Jquery UI Datepicker placeholder according to regional settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to have a datepicker initializated with a placeholder showing the dateFormat in use e.g. `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` etc.

The datestring format has to be the same used by the datepicker, and it is set by this part of code:

```
var locale= getUserLocale(); //eg 'en-US'        
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
            $.extend(
                $.datepicker.regional[locale]
            )
    );
```

So the placeholder has to bee different according to the regional datepicker settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the placeholder after initializing the datepicker(s):

```js
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);

$(function() {
  $("#datepicker-1").datepicker();
  $("#datepicker-2").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["zh-CN"]);

  $(".datepicker").each(function() {
    var dateFormat = $(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat");
    $(this).prop("placeholder", dateFormat);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css");

body {
  font: medium sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

<p>Default (fr):<br>
  <input id="datepicker-1" class="datepicker"></p>
<p>Chinese (zh-CN):<br>
  <input id="datepicker-2" class="datepicker"></p>
```